# The "Show on CV" button doesn't work

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Context:

- Firefox
- Windows 7

When I click on the "Show on CV" buttons, nothing happens except for a little error message at the bottom that says:

> Unable to find an account on Stack Apps matching this OpenID

I've checked the account profiles and they all point to the same OpenID.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Confirmed on Chrome; I'll mention it to the team

Comment: Confirmed, we are working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the report.  This should be fixed now. The message you're seeing regarding a non-existent StackApps account isn't an error (unless you do have a StackApps account), it's just informational.